# Layout manager map-element

Tags: qgis, layout-manager

I am wondering if there is some shortcut when you want the map element to update map-position to the position that the main window is showing, anything else can be the same (scale and so on)

Now am I dragging the map in the element to where i want the layout to be located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something is a daily action and feels clumbersome in QGIS, you probably should give it a lookup in the [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/index.html) - at lot of shortcuts have been introduced over the years.

For example, the button `set map canvas to match main canvas extent` ([image]) does exactly what you want. An explanation of all buttons in the map item properties can be found
[here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#the-toolbar).

Comment: thanks sometimes you just dont know where to look